# How to implement Asp.net membership in my developed web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am working on a web application. I already completed it. But when I gone through security audit, I came to know that I should use asp.net membership for, login, password change, creating user, reset password etc.

So I stared using asp.net membership. I created a login page and it's working fine. I also got a database in my App_Data folder.

[image]

The problem is that I already have a database for my application where I have a user table which is having more fields than the table aspnet_Users. see the image below.

[image]

So please suggest me how to implement asp.net membership in my web application, as I need more fields in user table,

how to insert data along with my fields with the fields above mentioned in the above image, because I didn't fine any code through using asp.net membership. If I could got,  I would surely make changes accordingly.

I mean how to merge this database and mine without any code.

Comment: Use Asp.net Profile you can insert as many as values.

Comment: but where to change the code if I want some other things along with this.

Comment: You will have to add the properties in web.config which you want to store and then add in profile and save the profile.When user will be authenticated you will set profile properties and save profile.

Comment: From experience, membership profiles are too limiting and unnecessarily complex to use. If I were you, I'd take a look at using ASP.NET Identity which is the new and much improved Membership system. http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: @Gaurav.. can you please look on it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924232/how-to-implement-asp-net-membership-in-mvc-project

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend that you use ASP.Net Identity as it is the framework for handling security.

However, if you are going to use simple membership, here is some code to help you "add fields" to your user table.

First, create your user model with all needed properties like so:

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Usernname is required.")]
    [StringLength(80, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value no more than 80 characters.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required.")]
    [StringLength(80, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value no more than 80 characters.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is required.")]
    [StringLength(80, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value no more than 80 characters.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [StringLength(254, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value no more than 254 characters.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

   //Add other properties... etc
}
```

Next, write the code to initialize your database. You probably have this code somewhere in the InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs file. Or, you can take it out from there and put in on your Application Start method. Here is the piece you need to modify:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("YourDBConnectionName", "User", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
//Modify the above properties if you change your user model to be a different table name
```

See reference to [InitializeDatabaseConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569134(v=vs.111).aspx).

Now, when you want to create a user, call the following method:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(user.UserName, user.Password, new { user.Email, user.FirstName, user.LastName });

//user is the User object that has all your data populated from some type of input
```

Reference to create user account: [CreateUserAndAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.createuserandaccount(v=vs.111).aspx)

Comment: Hello Praval. can you please look on it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924232/how-to-implement-asp-net-membership-in-mvc-project

Answer (score 0):

The one you are trying to implement is legacy **ASP.Net Membership Provider** created using **aspnet_regsql.exe**. *Do not use it, because it has been deprecated long time ago.*

Currently, Microsoft offers 3 types of Memberships -

1. [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)
2. Simple Membership Provider
3. ASP.NET Identity

Since your application is new and doesn't have existing users, you want to use -

[ASP.NET Identity 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx)

> The problem is that I already have a database for my application where
>   I have a user table which is having more fields than the table
>   aspnet_Users.

ASP.Net Identity lets you create custom fields in User table.

***FYI:*** Make sure you use Version 2.

Comment: Hello Win.. can you please look on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924232/how-to-implement-asp-net-membership-in-mvc-project